# text change of div element inside a button click function do not reflect permanently

Tags: javascript, html

I am changing text of div element on button click inside a function  but it do not reflect permanently. I mean on click of button it changes to "New text" but again it becomes "old text". Here is my code.

```
<form>
<input type="submit" onclick="myFun()" value="clickMe"/>
</form>
<div id="div1">old text</div>
```

and here is the javascript function.

```
function myFun(){
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "New text!"}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate about `but it do not reflect permanently`?

Comment: what do you mean by `do not reflect permanently. ` what you expect ?

Comment: I think he is about refreshing the page

Answer (score 2):

it should be of type `button` and not `submit`. Submit will refresh your page and your change will get lost. Or you could simply use the `button` element instead of an `input` field

```js
function myFun() {
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "New text!"
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button onclick="myFun()">clickMe</button>
</form>
<div id="div1">old text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change an element attribute it refreshes to the previous state after you refresh your browser. To make a permanent change, you need to modify source.

If you want user to complete the form without refreshing the page, you should add **return** to the onclick attribute, so it would look like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return myFun()" value="clickMe"/>
```

and then modify your JavaScript function **myFun()** to **return false;** at the end:

```
function myFun(){
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "New text!";
    return false;
}
```

It should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using submit so it will refresh page (redirected url) ,so use button or add return false will be ok

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFun();return false;" value="clickMe"/>
```